# when i am scrolling up, the navbar has to stick at top position and don't hide by following images of navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I make a code for sticking navbar at top position when i scroll down. But the problem is now when i scroll down the set fixed at top as i code. But the images which is following that navbar that hides navbar.

BEFORE SCROLLING

[image]

AFTER Scrolling
[image]

Lets see my code

```
       <div class="container">
    <h1>Mohamed faisal</h1>
    <p>Welcome to home page</p>
</div>

<div class="row" id="rows" >
    <div class="col-md-2 home" align="center" >Home</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 about" align="center">Department</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 home" align="center">Applications</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 about" align="center">Technologies</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 home" align="center">About us</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 about" align="center">Help</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
<br>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <div class="item active">
    <img src="f1.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Chania</h3>
      <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="f2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Chania</h3>
      <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="f3.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Flowers</h3>
      <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="f4.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Flowers</h3>
      <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

 $("document").ready(function ($) {
    var offsets = document.getElementById('rows').getBoundingClientRect();
    var topoffsets = offsets.top;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {

                if ($(window).scrollTop() > topoffsets) {

                           $("#rows").css({ top: 0, position: 'fixed' });

                        } else {
                           $("#rows").css({ top: '', position: '' });
                        }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this with a z-index on your navbar div. Add another class to your navigation div.

```
<div class="row navbar" id="rows" >
    <div class="col-md-2 home" align="center" >Home</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 about" align="center">Department</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 home" align="center">Applications</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 about" align="center">Technologies</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 home" align="center">About us</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 about" align="center">Help</div>
</div>
```

Then add the class to your css with a z-index of 99999.

```
.navbar {
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @wmeade, i got an output. could you tell me about z-index?.. thank you

Comment: `z-index` controls the stacking (or layering) of items on a page. Think of it loosely like a stack of paper. The top-most sheet on the stack has a high `z-index`, while the lower sheets have a lower `z-index`. So the lower the `z-index`, the "farther away" it will stack. By setting your navbar to `99999`, you're telling it to display on top of everything else on the page. Now you don't necessarily have to use such a high number, this just ensures it overwrites any other z-indexed properties on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use z-index to up the navbar layer.

```
.navbarclass {
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `div#rows` is your header here. You can apply `z-index`. I don't recommend the idea of `99999999` when dealing with large amount of z-index'd elements on the page. *you may need to increase according to the slider's index; inspect the slider's `z-index` property*

```
#rows {
   z-index: 1004;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `z-index` css property with high value on your navbar div.

**Code**

```
.navbar {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```